# Could a Virtual Adept create a virtual sanctum?

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension, umbra

Borrowing from [Jadasc](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/50/jadasc)'s premises, I had a thought based on the following:

### Premises

1. Magick cast within one own's Sanctum are always considered Coincidental, reducing the risk of Paradox.
2. The Virtual Adept's paradigm is one that posits the Universe is made of code.
3. The Digital Web is a physical space in the Umbra.
4. It is possible to manipulate the Digital Web from the real-world internet.

### Conclusions

1. Given Premise 3 it is possible to have a Sanctum in Digital Web.
2. Given Conclusion 1 and Premise 4, it is possible to upload code to the sanctum from the Internet.
3. Given Conclusion 2 and Premise 2, it is possible to cast Virtual Adept code-Magick without actually being in the Sanctum.
4. Given Conclusion 3 and Premise 1, it is *possible* for a Virtual Adept to cast certain Magick Coincidentally from anywhere with internet access.

Are any of my premises false? Is there a glaring mistep in my logic? Would there be another way of accomplishing the same outcome (Conclusion 4) within the mechanics? Ideally if Spheres are involved it should use the lowest level possible.

Comment: Which version of Mage? 1e, 2e, Revised or M20?

Comment: Since I'm not interested in being a rules-lawyer about what is essentially a story element I doubt it matters. But I had Revised in mind.

Comment: In case there's confusion regarding my edit, and since my edit comment was lost somehow, the edit was rolled back because I didn't realize the severe change in question format was done by the OP.  Once I realized my error, I rolled back the rollback.  My bad!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Question 1: Can a Virtual Adept create a virtual sanctum?**
Sure. That's carving out a spirit realm, which is Spirit •••••, Forge Ephemera. Doing so lets you make a pocket of digital space that remains permanently and is accessible to you. It's possible you might want to have someone else make it for you, if you're a new mage, or find an abandoned one.

**Question 2: How could you cast spells in that sanctum while remaining here in the physical world?**

That sounds like a combination Correspondence/Spirit effect to me: Spirit •• to extend yourself partially past the Gauntlet, and Correspondence •• to allow you to project yourself at a distance into that virtual space. You'd need to maintain that effect while you were doing something else, and whatever you did would have to remain in the scope of that sanctum. And you might want to avoid doing it in front of witnesses in case something went Catastrophically Wrong. But, yes. I think that's a successful means of doing that.

So, here's a worked example:

> Any kind of matter or energy creation would definitely make sense. Especially combined with a Coincidental Correspondence (pocket gateway) effect to get, say, a grenade.

You have your sanctum in the Digital Web. You establish a connection to it using your computer/smartphone focus (Corr 2/Spi 2); use the fab-lab/4D printer you stowed there to make it (Mat 3/Pri 2).

Now, whether the gateway in your pocket is Coincidental or Vulgar Without Witnesses would depend on your Storyteller, but you've definitely performed an act of vulgar magic in your Sanctum while still here in the Prime. Heck, if you didn't need it immediately, you could have it "delivered by Amazon drone" to where you were, coincidentally.

Comment: I clarified the premises and shifted them to the question, so you can edit your answer if you feel the need.

Comment: @WesleyObenshain Thanks! Here's a question that would help me improve my answer: Can you think of an effect or two that you'd want to cast that would be Vulgar outside the sanctum, Coincidental inside it, and would benefit if Conclusion 4 were true? That way, I can stress-test the idea.

Comment: Any kind of matter or energy creation would definitely make sense. Especially combined with a Coincidental Correspondence (pocket gateway) effect to get, say, a grenade.

Comment: @WesleyObenshain Interesting! I think that would work. You have your sanctum in the Digital Web. You establish a connection to it using your computer/smartphone focus (Corr 2/Spi 2); use the fab-lab/4D printer you stowed there to make it (Mat 3/Pri 2). Whether the gateway is Coincidental or VWW would depend on your Storyteller, but I believe the theory holds.

Answer (score 5):

This only applies to the 20th anniversary rules but there are a couple of points there that would pretty much prevent conclusion 4.

From M20, p469-470:

> As rough guidelines, however, the Storyteller can assume that most
>   forms of magick (in the Digital Web) are coincidental, with the following exceptions:
>
> - **Effects or gates that jump between sectors or that attempt to bridge    the Web with other areas of the Otherworlds.** With the
>     exception of    hot links – which have been specifically designed to
>     pop folks back    and forth between locations – an Effect that tries
>     to open new    passages from one sector to another, or from the
>     Digital Web into    some other Realm or Umbra, is considered vulgar
>     with witnesses… the    witness in question being the Web itself.
> - **Effects that jump from    Netspace to Meatspace…** because it’s one thing to watch something    morph onscreen, and another thing entirely
>     to watch your computer    turn into an asparagus.

Furthermore the rules on Sanctums don't appear to allow for virtual versions, M20 p323 states:

> Oh, this place still exists on the Earthly plane, and it’s subject to
>   the Paradox Effect.

In addition on the following page:

> All Effects cast within the Sanctum are considered coincidental
>   magick, so long as those Effects follow the definition of reality
>   within that sanctuary.

I also dug out a copy of the Digital Web 2.0 to see how this was handled in the revised edition and that also has the same restrictions:

> **Effects that jump from Netspace to RealSpace.** If Shiba flexes her VR
>   muscle to blow up a computer in Missis- sippi, her workings are
>   considered vulgar... usually with witnesses. (A Sleeper might accept a
>   cool morph, but would be nonplused if it was her computer that did the
>   morphing.)

So firstly, as far as the 20th anniversary rules are concerned you can't have a Sanctum within the Digital Web. However assuming a generous Story Teller allows it there is still the issue of effects only being Coincidental when cast within the Sanctum, casting from outside the Sanctum is not automatically Coincidental.

Secondly effects that go from Netspace to Realspace are almost always considered Vulgar, regardless of original source.

In conclusion, the rules do not support the conclusions in the question in any way and even bending the rules a fair bit shouldn't support premise 4. It's much like a Mage having only the Entropy sphere and attempting to have every effect count as Coincidental.

Comment: On the other hand none of that limits effects jumping from Meatspace to Netspace so if I WERE being a rules lawyer I'd point out that what isn't explicitly prohibited in a category is implied to be permitted. Also, the Coincidental vs Vulgar part refers to the natural state of the Digital Web. However, a Sanctum operates based on the paradigm of the Mage rather than the area around it so this shouldn't apply anyway.

Comment: Most of the storytellers I've known haven't been kind to Mages who like rules lawyering